# When was Ask Ubuntu founded?

Tags: support

I'm sure that this question must have been asked before, but I just can't find it anywhere, so I guess that I'm just searching for the wrong keywords. So I thought I'd ask, when was Ask Ubuntu founded? I mean when did the site first go online?

Comment: Well, here's [Question #1 by @NathanOsman on July 28th, 2010 @ 19:04 UTC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1/how-to-get-the-your-battery-is-broken-message-to-go-away)

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Area 51 proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716?phase=beta):

- public beta start: 2010-08-04 19:00:00Z (5 years ago)
- private beta start: 2010-07-28 19:00:00Z
- commitment start: 2010-07-12 17:21:43Z
- proposed: 2010-06-20 10:37:57Z

Comment: That is younger than I thought!

Comment: @NormalHuman I always assumed it was *much* longer before I noticed it...